# Centos 7 ISCSI diskless boot with ibft

Tags: centos, iscsi, dracut

I have diskless server system, based on Centos 7. It receives targets specified in NIC bios and boots.
The problem is - the system has very low iSCSI failure timeout, it fails in 5 seconds.
Here is what i tried: editing parameters in /etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf:

```
node.session.timeo.replacement_timeout = 86400
node.conn[0].timeo.noop_out_interval = 0
node.conn[0].timeo.noop_out_timeout = 0
```

It does not help.
I specified same parameters with `iscsiadm -T target -p ip -o update -n param_name -v value`
It didn't help
I specified those parameters in dracut config (it argues on unknown command rd.iscsi.param=), still nothing.

Maybe someone can suggest something?